# SQL Countif function

Tags: sql

I have a table like below

```
Type of Station | Broadcast Management
----------------+-------------------------
Full Power      | Sinclair Broadcast Group
Full Power      | Sinclair Broadcast Group
LPTV cable      | Sinclair Broadcast Group
LPTV no cable   | Sinclair Broadcast Group
```

Now I want to execute a query that will bring result looks like below

```
Broadcast Management       | Full Power | LPTV cable | LPTV no cable
---------------------------+------------+------------+--------------
Sinclair Broadcast Group   |  2         |     1      |  1
```

Can anyone please help me how to write this query

Answer (score 23):

There is no single `SUMIF` or `COUNTIF`.

But you do have `SUM`or `COUNT` and an *`IF`* using `CASE`...

```
SELECT
  [Broadcast Management],
  SUM(CASE WHEN [Type of Station] = 'Full Power'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS [Full Power],
  SUM(CASE WHEN [Type of Station] = 'LPTV Cable'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS [LPTV Cable],
  SUM(CASE WHEN [Type of Station] = 'LPTV No Cable' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS [LPTV No Cable]
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  [Broadcast Management]
```

For counts, you can make the `ELSE` return `NULL` as the count of `1, 2, 4, NULL` is `3`.

Comment: excellent. thanks @ MatBailie

Comment: And instead of CASE ... ELSE NULL END, you can just omit the ELSE NULL, since CASE returns NULL anyways if there's no ELSE.